# Calculation in a Probability Application Based problem

Tags: probability-theory

Let 1 starts with 0 points. He tosses a coin & if Head appears then he gets 1 point. If tell appears then he gets -1 points. But he can never start with -1. Hence find the probability for getting 20 points.......

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! I would suggest you to explain what you tried to do to solve the problem so other people could help you better. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the game starts when Head appears, then 20 points can be earned in the following way:

1. Get 20 heads one after the other
2. Get 1 tail and 21 heads (points = 21-1 = 20)
3. Get 2 tails and 22 heads (points = 22-2 = 20)
4. Get 3 tails and 23 heads (points = 23-3 = 20)... and so on.

So, the probability of getting 20 points is
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&(\frac{1}{2})^{20} + (\frac{1}{2})(\frac{1}{2})^{21} + (\frac{1}{2})^2(\frac{1}{2})^{22}+\cdots\\
&= (\frac{1}{2})^{20} + (\frac{1}{2})^{22} + (\frac{1}{2})^{24}+\cdots\\
&=(\frac{1}{2})^{20}(1+1/4+1/16+\cdots)\\
&=(\frac{1}{2})^{20}\frac{1}{1-1/4}\\
&=(\frac{1}{2})^{20}\times \frac{4}{3}
\end{split}
\end{equation}